# strtotime() not converting string to timestamp

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timestamp

I am trying to convert a string to a timestamp but it is just not happening.  This has gone above my expertise and from my googling, it looks like I shouldn't be seeing what I am seeing so I am thinking there is a bigger problem I am missing.

I am getting a date string from a WordPress function and then trying to use PHP to convert it. All I want from the string is the Month and Day (e.g. Mar 07) but I am failing to get anything date related:

```
error_reporting(-1);
$my_post_date = '{{ post_data:post_date_gmt }}';
echo $my_post_date;    // Result: 2017-03-07 01:35:43
var_dump($my_post_date);    // Result: string(29) "2017-03-07 01:35:43"

$timestamp = strtotime($my_post_date);
var_dump($timestamp);    //Result: bool(false)
```

I can't understand why that date string is breaking strtotime().

I have debugging on and there is no error_log so I can't see any errors.

UPDATE: The following has potentially identified the issue but it still has me confused...

```
var_dump(substr($my_post_date, 0, 3)); // Returns: string(3) "{{ "
```

Comment: works for me: http://ideone.com/JiE7XH

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($my_post_date)` instead of `echo`?

Comment: Added var_dump() of $my_post_date to original question

Comment: How does this string `'{{ post_data:post_date_gmt }}'` magically turn into a date?

Comment: https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Adding+Custom+Shortcode+to+Grid+Builder

Comment: Are you sure you have error reporting enabled correctly? Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of your script

Comment: Yep, added error_reporting(-1); above line 1 - some errors showed for unrelated issues but nothing for these lines of code - even went on server: ssh and search for files that had changed in past 24 hours- no hidden error_logs that i wasn't aware of

Comment: What about `display_errors`? While you're developing, it's much easier if the errors are displayed with the normal output. When `strtotime` fails, it should at least trigger an `E_NOTICE` or `E_WARN` level error

Comment: `{{ post_data:post_date_gmt }}` is being evaluated later than the lines you are running to convert to the datetime. What are you trying to achieve? "convert string to timestamp" is the step to your goal. Are you trying to get the datetime of a published post, the current post being created (which is what this looks like) or edit the date of the current post being created?

Comment: I just want the post day and month to display Mar 09

Comment: Wordpress has a function for that. Inside the loop, use [get_the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_date) or outside the loop, use [get_the_time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_time)

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that function but it's a little more complicated than that when using grid builder

Comment: You could either change the base format in WordPress settings (apparently Grid Builder uses that format), or use a filter that catches the Grid before output to turn the string into the format you want.

Comment: Changing the base format is ok but the full output is contained in <div> tags so I would still need to manipulate the string. This is all contained within add_shortcode( 'vc_custom_date', 'vc_custom_date_render' ); so the grid is just displaying this shortcode - I can't catch it any other way other than rewriting the whole section (which I'm starting to think is the only way)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137716/discussion-between-luke-and-php-b-grader).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your dumps/echos have their contents substituted after printing.

Proof of this is that `2017-03-07 01:35:43` is only 19 characters long but the vardump gives "str(29)". So what you're feeding strtodate is `{{ post_data:post_date_gmt }}` Which it obviously wouldn't recognise.

So Wordpress performs the substitution at a later point during the execution

Comment: Clearly that is the case but how? why? and if I can echo the string - how can I use the string?